# PHPExcel : combine multiple files (or worksheets) with style into one worksheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to combine multiple excel files (file1.xls;file2.xls). Both of which have the same number of columns and same type of column header.

I found a solution to combine data ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869207/phpexcel-combine-2-excel-files-into-1-into-the-same-worksheet)). But I want to copy the Styles ( I have different background for the differents files).

```
        $tempXlsFiles = [
            storage_path('exports') . "/file1.xls",
            storage_path('exports') . "/file2.xls"
        ];

        $objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tempXlsFiles[0]);

        for($i=1;$i < sizeof($tempXlsFiles); $i++){
            $objPHPExcelToCopy = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tempXlsFiles[$i]);

            // Find the last cell in the second spreadsheet
            $findEndDataRow = $objPHPExcelToCopy->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
            $findEndDataColumn = $objPHPExcelToCopy->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
            $findEndData = $findEndDataColumn . $findEndDataRow;

            $beeData = $objPHPExcelToCopy->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A2:' . $findEndData);

            // Identify the row in the first spreadsheet where we want to start
            // adding merged bee data without overwriting any bird data
            $appendStartRow = $objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() + 1;
            // Add bee data from the PHP array into the bird data
            $objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($beeData, null, 'A' . $appendStartRow);


            // How can i to add the style ?

        }
        // Save the spreadsheet with the merged data
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel1, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save(storage_path('exports').'/'.$outputFile);
```

PS : I use LaravelExcel and PhpExcel.

EDIT :

- file1.xls has 10 rows. This rows has background RED
- file2.xls has 5 rows. Has background BLUE

I want :
file_merge.xls : has 15 rows. 0 to 10 : background RED WITH data of file 1. 10 to 15 : data of file 2 with blue background.
(It's example, I don't know what background has file.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style inside for loop and add cell (A1, A2..., B1, B2...) as per requirement.

// Sample style :  border style : BORDER_THIN
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.'')->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set Style with the same styles of file1.xls and file2.xls. I made an Edit of my Post to explain

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simply reading an array of the sheet data values from one workbook, and setting those values in another; it will never copy the styles.

PHPExcel has a special method (`addExternalSheet()`) for precisely this purpose, and even provides [an example of using it (`43mergeWorkbooks.php` in `/Examples`)](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/43mergeWorkbooks.php).

```
$objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("templates/43mergeBook1.xlsx");

$objPHPExcel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("templates/43mergeBook2.xlsx");

foreach($objPHPExcel2->getSheetNames() as $sheetName) {
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel2->getSheetByName($sheetName);
    $sheet->setTitle($sheet->getTitle() . ' copied');
    $objPHPExcel1->addExternalSheet($sheet);
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel1, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("merged_with_styles.xlsx");
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want to include all files on same sheet. I don't want 1 file = 1 sheet.

Comment: Then you'll need to write code logic to copy the style information yourself; PHPExcel doesn't have any magic to provide that particular requirement

Comment: And because style IDs may differ between the files, it is still possibly best to use the approach that I've indicated to get all the data and styles synchronised into one workbook (across multiple worksheets) and then merge the data and style into the one worksheet as a second step using duplicateStyle() to copy the styles now that they've been synchronised, and all exist within the one workbook